# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection not established : Getting this error while processing more than 1k records

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jdbc, connection-pooling, spring-transactions

I am working on a spring boot application, which is processing more than 1k json messages in parallel and updating the database simultaneously with the respective fields.
Max 20 threads are running in parallel for this process.
It's running fine with less than 800 json messages.

For this bulk message scenario, I'm getting below error, whenever there is an DB update:

```
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Connection not established
2022-04-04 16:35:22.647  [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect@43a6bd0c: (connection is dead)
ERROR o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Failed to release JPA EntityManager
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to release JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.releaseConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:223)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.close(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:261)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.close(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.close(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:351)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.closeWithoutOpenChecks(SessionImpl.java:376)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.close(SessionImpl.java:361)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.closeEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:427)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(JpaTransactionManager.java:650)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1004)
```

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection not established
        at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:408)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.rollback(IfxSqliConnect.java:2324)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.close(ProxyConnection.java:257)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor230.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$ConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:202)
        at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:300)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.close(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.closeConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:127)
```

Data source properties configured:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
    tomcat:
       init-SQL: select col1  from table ( set {1} ) as x( col1 )
       default-transaction-isolation: 1
       initial-size: 10
       max-wait: 60000
       max-active: 200
       max-idle: 200
       min-idle: 100
       test-while-idle: true
       test-on-connect: true
       test-on-borrow: true
       test-on-return: true
       remove-abandoned : true
       remove-abandoned-timeout: 300
       time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 5000
       min-evictable-idle-time-millis: 60000
       validation-interval: 30000
       validation-query: select col1  from table ( set {1} ) as x( col1 )
       validation-query-timeout: 10
  jpa:
      open-in-view: false
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect
      show-sql: false
      properties.hibernate.format_sql: true
```

Can anyone please suggest/advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Hikari for connection pooling
I think you also need to manage properties of hikari

Kindly try to configure using these props:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.datasource.hikari

Comment: thanks @swapyonubuntu , I was able to solve this issue by adding below configs: spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 100
      minimum-idle: 2
      idle-timeout: 3600000
      connection-timeout: 500000
      leak-detection-threshold: 300000
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect
    show-sql: false
    properties.hibernate.format_sql: true

Comment: Some related articles for hikari pool sizing which helped me: https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/why-to-use-hikari-connection-pool-ce1a482cb9ab https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing

Comment: thats great! good to know